# Php PDO connection in postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, connection

i have a php script which is called again and again with in a interval of 4 seconds by ajax.

```
try {
    $conn_p = new PDO("pgsql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_dbname", $db_user, $db_password);
} catch(PDOException $e) {  
    //$e->getMessage();
}

function abc($id)
{
    global $conn_p;

    $st = "select * from table where id=:id";
    $sqlst=$conn_p->prepare($st);
    $bindParamArray=array("id"=>$id);
    $sqlst->execute($bindParamArray);   
    $row=$sqlst->fetch();   
    return $row;
}

function xyz($no)
{
    global $conn_p; 
    $st= "select * from table2 where no=:no and display='Y'";
    $sqlst=$conn_p->prepare($st);
    $bindParamArray=array(':no' => $no);
    $sqlst->execute($bindParamArray);   
    $row=$sqlst->fetch();   
    return $row;
}

function abc($id)
{
    global $conn_p;

    $st = "select * from table where id=:id";
    $sqlst=$conn_p->prepare($st);
    $bindParamArray=array("id"=>$id);
    $sqlst->execute($bindParamArray);   
    $row=$sqlst->fetch();   
    return $row;
}

function getData()
{
    global $conn_p; 
    $st= "select * from table2";
    $sqlst=$conn_p->prepare($st);
    $sqlst->execute();  
    $row=$sqlst->fetchAll();    
    return $row;
}
........same other functions

$data = getData();

foreach ($data as $dd) {

    $abc[] = abc($dd['id']);
    $xyz[] = xyz($dd['no']);
    //some other manipulations......
}

echo json_encode(array('data1'=>$abc,'data2'=>$xyz));
```

When running sql command

```
select * from pg_stat_activity
```

it is showing multiple connections.(told by my server admin to me)

Now my question is that:

- Should i need to close the connetion ?
- If yes, then when to close it ?
- And what if some error occurs ?

Comment: Depending on the specifics of your setup you might want to consider using the persistent connection. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: You should consider closing the PDO with: $conn_p = null;

Comment: ok, when to use $conn_p = null; I mean in my above script where to write it, at end of script or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. No, you do not need to close the connection unless your script runs for a long time and you are not using it while it is doing its time-taking manipulations. The connection will be closed automatically when the script finishes.
2. You should probably not fetch all rows from the database every x seconds. Only new or changed rows should be more efficient. And do you really need all rows in your page?
3. You should not run ajax calls using a short interval. Instead do an ajax call and set a timeOut for the next call when the current ajax call finishes. That way requests will never overlap.

Answer (score 0):

THis is what I use in my class for postgresql.
It is same as for mysql.

```
$this->dsn = $this->driver . ':host=' . $this->host . ';port=' . $this->port . ';dbname=' . $this->name;
```